# Jackson json parsing ignore property

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to compare 2 json strings but have to first remove the timestamp field.

Current code is like this:

```
    ObjectNode j1;
    ObjectNode j2;
    try {
        j1 = (ObjectNode) objectMapper.readTree(b1);
        j2 = (ObjectNode) objectMapper.readTree(b2);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // error handling
    }
    j1.remove(TIMESTAMP_FIELD);
    j2.remove(TIMESTAMP_FIELD);
    return j1.equals(j2)
```

now I was wondering if it wouldn't be easier to manipulate which fields jackson parses, so that I don't have to remove the fields afterwards. I looked around and only found solutions for mapping to POJO's, which doesn't work in my case since I just have a json string.

Does anybody know a better/faster solution?

Comment: `which doesn't work in my case since I just have a json string.` -> Please elaborate more

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn I just get random json-serialized objects from the database, I just know that it has a timestamp field